# How to prevent queue items from being processed twice

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

Using Entity Framework 6 against Sql Server 2014, I get a list of items to be processed which have a StatusId of 1.  After each item is processed, it is saved with a status of 2 so it does not get processed again.  Processing can take as long as several minutes.

However, this is not "Threadsafe" so-to-speak. In other words, if the code is started again (say by a different process) before the first one is complete, the status of the item is still 1, so it ends up in the Queue again and is processed a second time.

How can I get the records to be processed and ensure they are not retrieved a second time?  For example, is it possible to retrieve the data and update the status in a Transaction?

Comment: Why not create a third status "Processing" and set that once the work begins.

Comment: `lock` and/or `DbContext.Database.BeginTransaction()` ?

Comment: @entropic I like that idea combined with a Transaction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could wrap EF `transaction` inside `lock` statement to ensure only one thread is accessing the processing logic at any given time.

> The **lock** keyword marks a statement block as a critical section by
>   obtaining the mutual-exclusion lock for a given object, executing a
>   statement, and then releasing the lock.

```
private void ProcessEntities(IEnumerable<Entity> entities)
{
    lock (processLock)
    {
        using (var transaction = SomeDbContext.Database.BeginTransaction())
        {
            try
            {
                // process...
                // ...
                SomeDbContext.SaveChanges();
                transaction.Commit();
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                transaction.Rollback();
                Log(e);
                throw;
            }
        }
    }
}
```